# Why does this simple script background itself?

Tags: shell-script

Take the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Run some command in an interactive shell
$SHELL -ic '/usr/bin/env echo hello'

export IN_SHELL_TEST=true

# Launch a new $SHELL
$SHELL -i
```

The script for some reason stops every time I run it:

```
$ ./shell-test
hello


[1]+  Stopped                 ./shell-test

$ echo $IN_SHELL_TEST

$
```

I can bring it back with `fg`:

```
$ fg
./shell-test

$ echo $IN_SHELL_TEST
true

$
```

But this is not what I want! I want to launch a new shell and immediately start using it.

Comment: Seems to be the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/q/6431741 - the `i` in the `$SHELL -ic` line is the problem

Comment: @muru This doesn't seem related. That SO question is about how, _if_ the shell is backgrounded, then it gets stopped. The question here is about why the shell gets backgrounded.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Ubuntu 22.04. What OS are you running? Can you reproduce this without any shell initialization (`env -i SHELL=/bin/bash ./shell-test`)?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I don't think either post really cares about the hows or whys or whatevers of what's happening, or at least not as much as getting the scripts to simply work. I can repro it on Arch Linux with `SHELL=/bin/zsh`, zsh v5.9 and bash v5.1.16. And I can also get the script to work as intended by the OP by just changing `-ic` to `-c`.

Comment: @muru That seems like a bug somewhere, and not in the script. There's nothing in the script that would cause any process to be in the background. Testing further, I can reproduce this on Ubuntu 22.04 with `env -i SHELL=/bin/bash HOME=/none ./shell-test` (without explicitly setting `HOME`, bash sets it to my home directory from the user database), but not with my normal init files!